# Unable to upload zip file through karate framework

Tags: rest, karate

I am trying to upload a zip file through karate framework using the stack overflow reference: [put-requests-to-upload-a-file-in-form-data-using-karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload.feature) and karate documents [upload.feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload.feature)

Please find the code below:

```
Given path 'upload'
And header Content-Type = 'application/zip'
And multipart file code = { read: 'file:tests/create/export.zip', filename:'export.zip', contentType: 'application/zip' }
When method POST
Then status 200
```

We are getting the error as `httpStatusCode="500"><links/><message>No ZIP data entries were found to import.</message>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`multipart file`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#multipart-file) you don't set the `Content-Type`, and it will default to `multipart/form-data`. Which is most likely what you want - but no one will be able to tell without details about your server.

Work with someone from your server-side team if needed to resolve this. Or edit your question with a cURL command that *works* and maybe we can figure out what you are doing wrong.

There is a step by step process given here to help you get multi-part requests working, but it requires you to spend some time: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Also search for other answers on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+multipart

Else please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue