# Unable to upload an image using Karate Framework

Tags: karate

I am using https://apidocs.sirv.com/?shell#upload-file to explore upload feature of Karate Framework.

Below is Working cURL =

```
curl --location 'https://api.sirv.com/v2/files/upload?filename=%2Funtitled2.png' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer [pass your token]' \
--header 'Content-Type: image/png' \
--data '@/C:/Users/aadit/Downloads/220px-Selenium_Logo.png'
```

In Postman, I am passing file as Binary.
[image]

I need to pass file data as Binary content-encoding as mentioned in API doc. I tried with all possible content-type such as `application/octet-stream` & `image/png` but the uploaded image is corrupted i.e. data is not sent as binary. I tried multiple work around but couldn't get it working.

Karate Feature File

```
Feature: File Upload

Scenario: File Upload
Given url "https://api.sirv.com/v2/files/upload?filename=%2Funtitled1.png"
And header authorization = 'Bearer [token]'
And multipart field image = read('payloads/Untitled1.png')
And header Content-Type = 'image/png'
When method post
Then status 200
Given multipart file myFile = { read: 'payloads/Untitled1.png', filename: 'Untitled1.png', content-type: 'application/octet-stream' }
Then method post
Then status 200
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that's not a multipart request. Something like this should work, just add whatever headers you need.

```
* url 'https://api.sirv.com/v2/files/upload?filename=test.png'
* request read('test.png')
* method post
```

Multipart is very hard sometimes if you don't know what the server is expecting. If you still get stuck, use this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475