# How to handle Send and Download (as in postman) using Karate framework

Tags: rest, automated-tests, karate

I have a rest API that will download an Excel file (xlsx) on click of Send and Download in postman. I'm trying to automate this API using Karate framework. Can this be achieved?

The API returns a pre-filled name for the file and I want to retain it. Also, I want to specify particular location for the file to be downloaded.

Few more info about the API:

1. POST API
2. No headers required

I tried going throught the Karate JS APIs but no information was found regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Karate can handle a POST with binary data or a multipart equivalent to a file upload. Refer: [Unable to upload an image using Karate Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76887986/143475)

Downloading is simple, just a GET should work. You have to figure out the right URL, path and parameters though.

Refer to [this example](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.0/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload.feature) and the others in the same directory for more.