# Unable to upload binary file with Content-Type: application/x-java-serialized-object in karate

Tags: karate, binaryfiles

[image]
binary file content

Karate script we trying to run

```
    Feature: getSummary
 
Background: Setup
  * def constants  =  read(FEATURES_PATH + 'testfeatures/cc/hmm/common/MdsData.json')
  * callonce read(FEATURES_PATH + 'testfeatures/bb/cc/common/test.feature')
  * configure headers = ({'Content-Type': 'application/x-java-serialized-object','Accept': '*/*','Authorization': authCredentials,'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,br','remoteUsername':'xyz@zyz.com', 'executeAsRemoteUserFlag':true,Accept:HEADER_ACCEPT, Connection:HEADER_CONNECTION})
 
Scenario:  Binary content    
    Given url BASE_URL + '/txt/remote/Service/getSummary'
    And request read('test.txt')
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

Comment: that's insufficient info. see if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76888614/143475

Comment: No that won't be helpful, We are using Binary file and that file contains the java serializable object. content in the file something like this.    ¬í sr java.lang.Long;‹äÌ#ß J valuexr java.lang.Number†¬•”à‹  xp     )o

Comment: sorry I give up. hope someone here with more experience with this can help you, all the best. also please refer stack overflow guidelines and see if you need to revise your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry if I am not being clear. I have updated description with screenshots. if that helps you to understand. Please help on this, we got stuck in middle with this issue.

Comment: I am trying to guess a solution and posted an answer. let me know if it works. if it does not, I have no other suggestions. note that images don't help at all (read the above link again). also if you are trying to do a large postman to karate migration, we can help (commercial): https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7112796652624560128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only suggestion I have is try this - since you are working with binary. Which cannot be treated as plain text.

```
And request karate.readAsBytes('test.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Peter, it worked like charm!

Comment: @Sunitha that is good to know. please accept the answer so it helps others: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers