# Part content ID cannot be blank for non root MIME parts - Getting this error while running a POST api call using karate framework

Tags: xml, karate

While passing the xmlPayload and jpg image as multipart attachment using karate getting the error.

Code am using:

```
Scenario: Passing the multipart Attachments
* def xmlPayload = read('classpath:data/xmlAttachment.xml')
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"'
And header MIME-version = '1.0'
And multipart file image = { value: '#(image)', filename: "image.jpg, contentType: "image/jpeg"}
And multipart file xmlAttachment = { value: '#(xmlPayload)', filename: "xmlAttachment.xml, contentType: "text/xml"}
When method POST
Then status 200
```

I tried some approaches like by changing the content Type to multipart/mixed, multipart/form-data and in the multipart request i added some parameters like contentID, boundary. But nothing got worked.

Can you please help us to fix this issue.

Comment: sorry, multipart is one of those things that is near impossible to troubleshoot without access to your server, so you are on your own. refer to this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475