# Getting 400 response code error for upload and download .jar files using karate framework

Tags: automation, get, postman, karate

I am doing automation for upload/download operation for .jar files using karate framework but I am getting 400 error code response. The sample code is as follows:

Given upload appserver
And path '/integration/rest/edge/flow/download'
And multipart file file `jar = { read:'helloworld.jar', filename:'helloworld.jar', Content-Type:'multipart/form-data' }`

```
def reqpayload = {}
reqpayload.agentID = "3567tfhjj57i8i668"
reqpayload.agentGroup = "default"
reqpayload.apiendpoint = "/package/Testproj/jar?static=true"
reqpayload.httpmethod = "GET"
```

And request reqpayload
And headers `{ Content-Type: 'Application/json', Authtoken: 'tdd78885bjj', Cookie: 'fyffufufuy5i57fyg', x-csrf-token: 'ydyf5uggi'}`
When method get
*match responseStatus == 500

I am getting 400 error. As per the functionality verified in postman I should get 500. Please let me know how to resolve it.

Tried changing the content type to different values. Expecting some solution for handling upload/download of jar file using karate framework.

Comment: a lot depends on your server and especially multipart upload can be hard. all I can do is point you to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475