# How to set multipart form-data with boundary in karate framework

Tags: karate

Below is the java code which works fine and I am trying to do the exactly same thing in karate framework.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path_to_json_file"))) );
        String apiUrl = "my_url";
        String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();

        HttpEntity requestEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addTextBody("param_name",jsonString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .build();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(apiUrl);
        httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", requestEntity.getContentType().getValue());
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer_Token");


        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                System.out.println("Response Status Code: " + statusCode);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And below is the karate scenario to do the same thing:

```
Feature: Test Java code

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * header Authorization = baseAuth

  Scenario: Verify API execution
    Given path 'my_url'
    And def inp_json = read('path_to_json_file')
    And multipart fields { param_name: '#(inp_json)' }
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

Now when I run this scenario, then I am getting error that "HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported\n". So do i need to set something in karate for the java counter part of "httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", requestEntity.getContentType().getValue())" ?
Sorry if I missed something here and thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, multipart is the hardest thing to figure out sometimes. all I can do is point you to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475

Comment: thanks @PeterThomas for the confirmation. I was able to use all the above code using java class actually.