How to send a Post request in Karate with Form data file (binary)
I am getting 415 error code.below is my karate code

def query = {
definitionType: 'Standard',
equipmentType: 'Machine'
}
header 'Accept-Encoding' = 'gzip, deflate, br'
header 'Connection' = 'keep-alive'
def Id = 12
def authorization = 'Bearer dhjrh'
url data.baseurl + data.definurl
Given path 'Bxml'
And params query
def htmlFile = read('src/test/java/features/P/1mb.html')
When method post {multipart field file: htmlFile, filename: '1mb.html'}
Then status 200


sorry, multipart is hard you shouldn't be setting headers like accept and connection. try this thread and be prepared to do some investigation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475
