Testing uploading file by karate : Unsupported Media Type
I am trying to test uploading a pdf file by karate, and I am getting the following error.
here is my endpoint to upload file
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/files")
public class UploadController {
    @PostMapping
    public @RequestMapping(
            value = "/upload",
            produces = {"application/json", "application/problem+json", "application/pdf"},
            consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}
    )
    String upload(@RequestParam("myFile") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        return "Success";
    }
    }

And my karate test:
Scenario: Upload a pdf file
    Given path '/files/upload'
    And header Accept = 'application/pdf'
    And multipart file myFile = { read: 'test.pdf',fileName: 'test.pdf', contentType: 'application/pdf'  }
    When method post
    Then status 200

Error:
status code was: 415, expected: 200, response time in milliseconds: 5, url: http://localhost:61761/files/upload, response: 
{"title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"detail":"Content-Type 'application/json;boundary=22459011c7e35efa' is not supported"}


multi-part requests are tricky, and impossible to help without access to your server - so I can only point you to this answer that should hopefully give you enough info to troubleshoot and solve this yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475
