Multipart POST request not working in Karate 1.4.1 but worked with Karate 1.2.0 and the same API call working fine in POSTMAN
I'm trying to upload a file through a multipart post request api in karate, however I have been getting a response  ` 400 - an error stating status code was: 400, expected: 200, response time in milliseconds: 135, url: .., response:  {"type":"about:blank","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"Failed to read request","instance"}.   ` But when i hit the same api in postman with the exact same file it is working fine without any errors. Anyone know what reason that would be causing this issue? The api input is a file in form-data.  I have checked the headers of both calls from postman and karate, no issues has been found - they are the same.  Below is the multipart request body I have tried adding * configure charset = null to the karate test but it still sends utf-8 in the multipart request. I also observed that the content-length is different from the request sent from postman and from the request sent in karate. For example the same request in postman has content-length as 773 while the request sent from karate has content length 750.
Below is an example code that i have


2 > Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=d897c2bfb387d758
2 > Content-Length: 557[text]
2 > Host: gfciu-gateway-dk1986-f.uki1f.paas.intranet.db.com
2 > Connection: Keep-Alive
2 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/17.0.11)
2 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

content-disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="17.png"
content-type: image/png
content-length: 129
Completed: true
IsInMemory: true

content-disposition: form-data; name="meta"; filename=""
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 132
Completed: true
IsInMemory: true`

  Scenario: create an entity 

    Given path 'api/entity/entities'
    And request entyOrg
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And def entyresponse1 = response
    And def entityId1 = entyresponse1.id
`
    * def filePath1 = read('file:src/test/java/test_data/17.png')
    * def docPayload1 = [{ "entityId": '#(entityId1)', ref": "ENTITY", filename: "17.png" , contentType: "image/png" }]`


Has anyone experienced something similar where are multipart request works on postman but not karate?

    Given path  'api/document/documents/v2'
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    And multipart file content = { value: '#(filePath1)', filename: "17.png", contentType: "image/png" }
    And multipart field meta = { value: '#(docPayload1)', filename: "17.png", contentType: "application/json" }
    When method post
    Then status 200



please refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475

curl --location 'https://gfciu-gateway-dk1986-f.uki1f.paas.intranet.db.com/api/document/documents/v2' 
--header 'Cookie: SESSION=fae0c31c-515c-4a6a-b99c-d496f70cba09' 
--form 'content=@"postman-cloud:///1ef50dcd-32b1-4d20-9597-cc4a26da2a48"' 
--form 'meta="[{"entityId":24637,"entityRef":"PROJECT","fileName":"17.png","contentType":"image/png"}]";type=application/json' -->I have provided the curl, can you have a look as i am still not able to resolve the issue

below is the error i get.
status code was: 400, expected: 200, https://gfciu-gateway-dk1986-f.uki1f.paas.intranet.db.com/api/document/documents/v2, response:
{"type":"about:blank","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"Failed to read request","instance":"/api/document/documents/v2"}
can you please check and let me know what needs to be changed. @PeterThomas

Hi I have updated to Karate 1.5.0 and tried again * def filePath1 = read('classpath:test_data/17.png')
* def docPayload1 = [{"entityId":25008,"entityRef":"PROJECT","fileName":"17.png","contentType":"image/png"}]
* path 'api/document/documents/v2'
* header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
* multipart file content = { value: '#(filePath1)', filename: "17.png", content-Type: "image/png" }
* multipart file meta = { value: '#(docPayload1)' , filename: "17.png", content-Type: "application/json" }
* method post
* status 200


curl --location 'https://server/api/document/documents/v2' 
--header 'Cookie: SESSION=777777' 
--form 'content=@"postman-cloud:///1ef50dcd-32b1-4d20-9597-cc4a26da2a48"' 
--form 'meta="[{"entityId":24637,"entityRef":"PROJECT","fileName":"17.png","contentType":"image/png"}]";type=application/json'
