How to upload Multiple files with multipart/form-data in karate framework
I want   to upload multiple PDF files in one request using multipart, but the multiple file upload is not working with below code.
Example : 1
Scenario: Upload multiple files
    
    Given path '/upload' 
  And multipart file files = { read: '../TestData/file1.pdf' },{ read: '../TestData/file2.pdf' }
    When method post
    Then status 200

Example : 2
Scenario: Upload multiple files
    
    * def json = {}
    * set json.files[0] = { read: 'file1.jpg', filename: 'file1.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpeg' }
    * set json.files[1] = { read: 'file2.jpg', filename: 'file2.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpeg' }
    Given path '/upload' 
    And multipart files json
    When method post
    Then status 200

Example : 3  only with below code  the multipart is working but we don't want to use multiple times multipart
Scenario: Upload multiple files
    
    Given path '/upload' 
  And multipart file files = { read: '../TestData/file1.pdf' },
  And multipart file files =   { read: '../TestData/file2.pdf' }
    When method post
    Then status 200

https://github.com/ptrthomas?tab=packages

I am not sure, but try this:
And multipart files [{ name: 'files', read: 'file1.pdf' }, { name: 'files', read: 'file2.pdf' }]

If you keep the same name, I think it will append to an array.
There can be bugs as this is a rare use case. You can try debug and contribute code. Since multipart is very tricky, refer this thread if needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475
