Karate multipart POST request returning "Virus Detected!" error
I am trying to attach a .png file as a multipart file in POST request to an Apigee endpoint however, it keeps on getting rejected and returns "Virus Detected!" error. When I try the same using CURL command, it works fine. I have tried to follow various post and documents but no success so far. Did someone face a similar issue?
Karate POST request:
Given path url
        And header x-client-version = *version*
        And header client-id = *client-id*
        And header Authorization = *token*
        And header Accept = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
        And multipart file document = {read:'image.png', filename: 'image.png', contentType: 'image/png'}
        When method POST
        Then status 200



Getting this response with status 403:
{
        "error": {
            "status": "403",
            "code": "FORBIDDEN!",
            "message": "Virus Detected!"
        }
    }


Curl request:
curl --location 'url' \
    --header 'x-client-version: *version*' \
    --header 'client_id: *id*' \
    --header 'Authorization: *token*' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
    --header 'Cookie: *cookie*' \
    --form 'document=@"/path/image.png"'

I made some attempts to resolve this:

adding "And configure charset = null" but still running into "Virus Detected!"
Adding Content-Type header with value image/png, and got "requested URL was rejected" status 406.
Changing file name and location, got "Virus Detected!"
Changing the file payload with multiple other .png files, but constantly running into "Virus Detected!"

Tried doing the multipart POST request in Postman with the exact same file succeeds with no errors.
Thanks!

multi-part is hard. you can follow these instructions here (maybe put curl in verbose mode) and then you might be able to figure out how to get the karate call to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475

hi @PeterThomas, i couldn't successfully debug but found a work-around with:
def response = karate.exec(``curl --silent --compressed --location '${url}' --header 'client_id: ${client_id}' --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' --header 'Authorization: ${token} --header 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' --header 'x-client-version: ${version}' --form 'document=@${imagePath};type=image/png'``)
which works with no errors. Any ideas on why it would work this way but not when using Given-When-Then format?
Thanks
