Karate API - Zip File Upload - http call failed - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
I have a karate feature where there is a POST multipart form request for uploading zip file. I don't have access to the server to be able to debug it or see how the code is written there. Here is the feature file snippet:
    * def zipFileName = 'testFile.zip'
    * def zipFileAddress = "classpath:testData/" + zipFileName
    * def zipFile = { read: "#(zipFileAddress)", filename: "#(zipFileName)" }
    Given path 'upload/files'
    And header Media-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
    And multipart file file = zipFile
    And multipart field projectId = projectIdParam
    And multipart field transactionId = 'PDD-74232'
    And multipart field clientId = pdClientId
    And multipart field callbackUrl = ''
    * karate.logger.info("Request: " + karate.pretty(zipFile))
    When method post
    Then status 201

Below is the error message,
com.intuit.karate - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException, http call failed after 754 milliseconds for url.
Http call is failing but the file is uploaded successfully.
Zip file in project directory is accessible and the size of file is less than 100mb which is expected.
I am trying to upload zip file from karate api feature, getting http call failed error but the file is uploaded successfully. The expectation is we should not get the http call failure and the test execution should be done for other validations.
Because of the http call failure, I am not able to validate the status code and other response.
The same is working in SoapUI and I am getting expected results. I am using the same headers and params in Karate as I use in SoapUI. Can anyone help me with the issue. Thanks in advance!

please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891444/143475
